# Skype for Windows 8.1 not working

Tags: windows-8.1, skype

I can't login to Skype for Desktop on Windows 8.1.

Login works on Skype.com, also works on other computers.

I deleted %appdata%/skype, ran CCleaner, reinstalled Skype, still not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Skype for Windows 8.1 is useless as a shoe (excluding agent 86's shoe). I'd uninstall it and I use "skype for desktop", that is Win7 or less

Comment: Read the question Leandro; he is using the desktop version; and the windows store version being useful or useless is a personal opinion

Comment: @Adam your are using the current version of Skype and your using your Microsoft Account credentials, correct?

Comment: Ramhound, I'm using the current version of Skype, but with skype.com username and password credentials

Comment: What is the reason it gives you for failing when you try to log on?

Comment: It tells me "Sorry, we didn't recognize your sign-in details" even though i can login to skype.com, and skype works on other computers.

Answer (score 0):

@Leandro I use Skype for Desktop in Windows 8.1 and it works perfectly.

1. Make sure Windows Update is up to date, it *might* be the reason.

> "Sorry, we didn't recognize your sign-in details"

Did you choose the correct sign-in option on Skype?

You can choose between **Skype Name** and **Microsoft Account** in the **Sign in** menu.

Since you want to login with skype.com username and password credentials, did you choose to login with **Skype Name**?

[image]

Choosing to sign-in with Skype Name will lead to this:

[image]

Choosing to sign-in with a Microsoft Account will lead to this:

[image]

If you choose to login using Skype Name and it still doesn't work, what happens when you click **"Can't Access Your Account?"**?